# How to make parts of an image separately clickable and changeable -how to create a 2d/3d designer with html5 canvas or something else?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a 2d or 3d designer for handbags (where users can create their own bag by clicking on parts of he bag and choosing the color or material ) for example like on shoesofprey.com I was looking into html5 canvas as it seems the right framework for that but not sure at all how to split a picture (or photoshop drawing) into many elements (so users can click on each element to change its color etc). I was also going to use angular. Would be great if someone could give me some tipps about html5 canvas or perhaps there is another way of making parts of a drawing or image clickable and changeable?! Thanks

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
//just an example for a picture
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" id="background" />
  var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
document.getElementById('background');
var ballon = document.getElementById('ballon')
context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This isn't a tutorial or recommendation service. You will need to research this yourself. start by examining the code in your example. Come back when you run into problems with code that doesn't behave as expected and you will get lots of help then

Comment: I wanted to ear what people in general would use-html5 canvas or something else and how to get parts of a picture. I didn't ask for a tutorial on html5 canvas or anything. if my question bothers you, just kindly ignore it.

Comment: Well unfortunately that's just not how this site works.... see [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I am not sure why you mark my question as a duplicate or why you can't just move on and leave me alone-seriously!My question has nothing to do with the answer postet to the other question-maybe read fully before marking my question as a duplicate